# Holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function such that for an open interval  $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ the following holds: $f(V)=0$. Does there exist an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(U)=0$.

Intuitively I would say it is true. I haven't been able to construct a counter example yet.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ an open subset?

Comment: Meromorphic functions in one variable have isolated zeroes and singularities

Comment: @AndreaMori: *nonconstant*.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: non zero, actually :)

Comment: Isn't this an implication of the strong form of the identity theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly true. In fact, if $f$ and $g$ are entire holomorphic functions and $f = g$ on a set $E$ with an accumulation point, then $f = g$ everywhere, so your set $U$ can be taken as the whole complex plane.

See for example [Wikipedia: Identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does the identity theorem also hold for a holomorphic function of the form $f: \mathbb{C}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ or $f: \mathbb{C}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n $?

Comment: Variants hold in higher dimension, but the sets of uniqueness are larger. For example $f(z,w) = z$ and $g(z,w) = 0$ agree on $\mathbb{C} \times \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Ah, that is nice. Does the proof for the extension of the multivariable case directly follow from the identity theorem in one complex variable?

Comment: That $f = g$ on an open set implies $f = g$ everywhere is usually proven the same way as in the one variable case (via power series), but the more refined versions are more difficult.

Comment: For the refined versions to which literature would you refer me?